# How can I sample from a Gaussian distribution with a precomputed mu(k,n) and a covariance(k,k) matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian

I have a list of weights from various experiments, each weight with dimensions `(k,4)` k `samples`, 4 `features`. My task is to fit a `Gaussian distribution` with these weights and then sampling from the distribution.

[image]

The closest I found is `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` but unfortunately accepting a 1-D array. So i apply it in every feature of my mean with the same covariance for all.
Below there is an implementation of what I am describing, the fit of the Gaussian and the sampling from it and the results that I get seams fine but I am not sure if this is the right implementation.

```
    def muSigmaCalculation(weights,k):
        mean = np.zeros((k,4))
        for i in weights:
            mean += i
        mean /= len(weights)
    
        covariance = np.zeros((k,k))
        for i in weights:
            covariance += np.dot((i-mean),(i-mean).T)
        covariance /= len(weights)
    
        return mean,covariance
    
    n = 4
    k = 30
    weights = [np.random.rand(k,n) for i in range(10)]

    mean, covariance = muSigmaCalculation(weights,k)

    test = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean[:,0],covariance)
    for i in range(1,4):
        test = np.vstack((test,np.random.multivariate_normal(mean[:,i],covariance)))
```